# google analytics can not see the code on the site

Tags: google-analytics, counter

GA code is placed just before `</head>` tag, but
for more than 3 days i still get "code is not installed"
here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18367XXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

probably there could be some special settings on a server??
(in robots.txt for example - nothing special)

Comment: Do you have a URL for your site where the code should be installed?

Comment: The `UA-18367XXX-1` needs to be replaced with your actual account number, if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 1):

The code itself works fine, sends data to GA just fine all by itself.

You need to supply more info than just a c/p of the code generated, but in general....

1) Data is sent to GA by actually going to and viewing the page in your browser.  So it doesn't matter what is in robots.txt.  But if this is not on a page that you actually go to and view in your browser, then data will not be sent.

2) Ensure that you have the right account number in this line:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18367XXX-1']);
```

I assume you XXX'd out your account number for posting purposes but you know what they say about assuming...

3) Make sure you are looking at the right account/report(s) in GA.

4) Make sure you don't have any filters or anything blocking the page(s) in question (or whole domain)

Other than those things to check...can't much help without more details.

Comment: well none of it unfortunately ((